# Source code organization in a Xcode projects with frameworks using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I had a project with the following structure:

App project

|--- Framework 1

|--- Framework 2

Framework 1 and 2 are frameworks which are similar. Basically those two frameworks are using some library in CocoaPods. But CocoaPods needs to be Workspace. How can I add workspace to another workspace? Or I can't use CocoaPods in my case? Anybody has experiences at this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the X targets and the pod project with its 1 project with Y targets can all kept in one workspace...

it doesnt matter if you have a project for your Y targets or a workspace...

in the first case cocoa pods will add a new workspace in the second it will add its project to the existing workspace

Comment: just make a pod file for the project and include the pod dependencies there